# How can i get the Flash real url in <object> by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

The Flash movie is in the object, when the Flash movie is playing I check the element in Chrome, and the code is like this:

```html
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s2.pstatp.com/site/video/player.swf" width="100%" height="100%" id="vjs_video_3_Flash_api" name="vjs_video_3_Flash_api" class="vjs-tech">
<param name="movie" value="http://s2.pstatp.com/site/video/player.swf">
<param name="flashvars" value="readyFunction=videojs.Flash.onReady&amp;eventProxyFunction=videojs.Flash.onEvent&amp;errorEventProxyFunction=videojs.Flash.onError&amp;autoplay=false&amp;preload=auto&amp;loop=false&amp;muted=undefined&amp;">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="allowNetworking" value="all"><param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
</object>
```

I can't see the embed.  Why can it play without the embed? Now I have got the `<object>` element by `document.getElementsByTagName('object')` in the Chrome console, but how can I get the Flash URL with JavaScript?

Comment: by the way, the url in data and value is not the real flash's url

Comment: try `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('object'), function(obj) { console.log(obj.data);})`

Comment: which is real flash url?

Comment: @ParagBhayani - why do you need to know the real one - clearly he doesn't want to share that piece of information, as it isn't relevant

Comment: @JaromandaX: I mean which parameter is a real url here? is it from param movie? I need to confirm that...

Comment: it would be `object data` AND the `value` of `param name="movie"` - if memory serves me correctly, they are often the same with flash - it's been so long since I plunged to the depths of flash :p

Comment: `I can't see the embed. Why can it play without the embed?` embed was old school way for some browsers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function getMovieUrl(obj) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(obj.children, function(param) {
    if (param.getAttribute('name') === 'movie') {
      return param.geAttribute('value');
    }
  });
  return null;
}
```

Comment: best to use `children` rather than `childNodes` - avoids processing text nodes - besides, if you have the object, it's just `obj.data` ...

Comment: Thanks. I'll update about children, but OP said the true URL isn't in the data attribute, so I went on the next best thing

Comment: Which, on second glance, isn't useful either. Huh.

Comment: I think he meant that he's not sharing the actual flash movie, but seeing as data and movie value are the same ...

Comment: I must have misunderstood, that makes sense

Comment: don't take my word for it though ... sometimes those sort of statements can mean something totally unexpected :p